# Make Background image Click able

Tags: jquery, maps

I have map and that map is divided seperator based on color,

each portion i want to make it clickable,

any idea how can i implement it using jquery. or any other idea. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Make it an SVG.

Comment: Or you could go old school and use an image map: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map. SVG is by far the best way, though

Comment: Thanks SVG works for me